# need to save a global variables coming from the same function() in python()

Tags: python, function, numpy, global

I made a toy function where I would need to save certain values that are given to this function... to perform this I usually declare this storing variable `x` as global..

But if I need to call this function several times inside the same code, the same global var `x`obviously will be the result of each time the function is called.

How can I obtain this simple task?

this below is the toy example.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def _foo_append_(x_i,count):               
    global x

    if count==0:
        x = []

    x.append(x_i)

    return x


for i in range(0,10):
    rv_1 = np.round(np.random.normal(10,5),decimals=2)
    rv_2 = np.round(np.random.normal(22,3),decimals=2)

    keep_1 = _foo_append_(x_i=rv_1,count=i)
    keep_2 = _foo_append_(x_i=rv_2,count=i)
```

the output should be two arrays `keep1` and `keep2` of 10 elements both, but I'm getting both arrays of 20 elements..

How to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: This is the entire problem with using global variables; state tends to "leak" which makes everything more difficult than necessary.  Why don't you just create the two arrays outside of the function and pass them in, so you can pass a different one to each function call?

Comment: This is what classes are for, though you could also simply create a dict of lists, and replace `_foo_append` with a call to the appropriate list's `append` method.

Comment: @Barmar I used global, I was trying how nonlocal would have behaved

Comment: @Samwise because I would need to use this function many times inside the same code... So I would like to avoid declaring, let's say 20 arrays, keep0, keep1, keep2, ..., keep19. I would like python to have a "specialglobal" that creates a temporary new global until the running process ends... python should create x0, x1, x2, ...., xN temporary globals. I would like to have that option

Comment: @chepner could you provide a small example? will a class allow me to do this?

Comment: If you have 20 lists and 20 sets of `np.random.normal` parameters, you still need to declare them separately, unless the parameters follow some sort of pattern that you can generate programmatically.  If they do follow a pattern, just make a list of lists, or a dict of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using global/nonlocal variables makes it difficult to keep the different lists straight, since they both share the same name in the same scope.  You should instead initialize each array separately.

Your example could be written much more simply (and correctly) as:

```
import numpy as np


keep_1 = [np.round(np.random.normal(10,5),decimals=2) for _ in range(10)]
keep_2 = [np.round(np.random.normal(22,3),decimals=2) for _ in range(10)]
```

If your "real" example is more complex and you can't use a list comprehension, or you can't actually declare the different `keeps` as different named variables, here's an example that uses your `_foo_append_` (minus the unnecessary global var stuff it's just a simple call to `append`) and a list of lists that keeps track of the `keep_n` lists:

```
def _foo_append_(x, x_i):
    x.append(x_i)


params = [(10, 5), (22, 3)]
keeps = []
for p in params:
    keeps.append([])
    for _ in range(0, 10):
        _foo_append_(keeps[-1], np.round(np.random.normal(*p), decimals=2))
```

Comment: `np.random.normal` takes a `size` argument that let's you skip the `for` loop entirely